# running query for array elements

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
foreach($paradise as $nepal)
{
  $qry="select * from img where name='$nepal'";
  $ktm = mysql_query($qry);
  while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($ktm))
  {
    ?>
    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" height="200px" width="200px">
    <?php
  }
}
?>
```

I want to run queries for all $paradise array elements. This code works just fine but I assume this is not a correct way to do. I know a single query can handle this but I don't get it. Help me!!

Comment: is the values of `$paradise` also coming from the database?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `IN` statement on sql:
In your code, it should be like this:

```
<?php

  $names = implode("','", $paradise);
  $query = "select * from img where name in ('{$names}');";
  $ktm = mysql_query($query);
  $images = "";
  while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($ktm)) {
    $images .= '<img src="uploads/'. $result['image'].'" height="200px" width="200px">';      
  }
  echo $images;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the WHERE IN clause.

For example:

```
select * from img where name in ('hello', 'world', 'stackoverflow');
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the array usable in query, put the array element as string. Like using IMPLODE or manual way:

```
$count=0;
Foreach ($paradise as $nepal){
    If($count==0){
        $string = $nepal;
    }else{
        $string = $string.",".$nepal;
    }
    $count++;
}
```

As people suggesting using IN in WHERE clause, you should definitely try it with $string variable above. But in simple way, you can use OR in WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name="x" OR name="y" OR name="z";
```

Generating string in manual way will be like:

```
$count=0;
Foreach ($paradise as $nepal){
    If($count==0){
        $string = "name='".$nepal."'";
    }else{
        $string = $string." OR name='".$nepal."'";
    }
    $count++;
}
```

Put together your 'loop generated string' in your query string and your code is good to go.